# Разбор содержимого web-страницы из .sh (shell-скрипта)

Tags: linux, автоматизация

Всем привет. Я работаю на хостинге игровых серверов. 
Меня недавно повысили в уровне доступа, и я начал переделывать некоторые скрипты автоматизации.

Столкнулся с 1 затруднением.
[image: Код скрипта]

Нужно доделать установку самой свежей версии модов. На данный момент название архивов с самыми свежими модами mmsource-1.10.7-git961-linux.tar.gz и sourcemod-1.8.0-git6036-linux.tar.gz.

Подскажите как выполнять парсинг с сайта, на самую свежую версию , чтобы не менять в ручную переменные mmver и smver , может есть какие-либо функции ? 
Сайты : [Metamod](https://mms.alliedmods.net/mmsdrop/1.10/)
[Sourcemod](https://sm.alliedmods.net/smdrop/1.8/)

Comment: Зачем что то парсить, там же лежит файл mmsource-latest-linux получаете его wget в нем написана последняя версия

Comment: Подскажите тогда пожалуйста как задать переменной то, что храниться на страничке https://sm.alliedmods.net/smdrop/1.8/sourcemod-latest-linux ?

Comment: скачиваете его wget куда нибудь в определенное место и для его использования можете писать `wget https://..../\`cat имя-файла\`` (обратите внимание, апострофы обратные)

Comment: Посмотрите как работает watch в пакетах deb. Кратко: там записано регулярное выражение, программа получает список файлов, фильтрует с помощью регулярного выражения и выбирает последнюю по алгоритму сравнения версий.

Answer (score 2):

При таком раскладе будет как раз выплёвываться последняя версия:

Через curl:

```
mmver=$(curl --silent https://sm.alliedmods.net/smdrop/1.8/sourcemod-latest-linux)
```

Через wget:

```
mmver=$(wget -q -O - https://sm.alliedmods.net/smdrop/1.8/sourcemod-latest-linux)
```